# Dropbox redirect URI does not redirect for login, instead returns code of last user

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox Code API version 2 from NodeJS application. I am using OAuth 2.0 with code grant approach. It seems to behave randomly. The use case is as follows:

1. My server generates a redirect uri and sends to my client.
2. User clicks on redirect uri from client.
3. Application redirects to Dropbox URI.  (User has already linked my app to their Dropbox. My app has full Dropbox permission.)
4. Dropbox asks to sign in with google or email. I used gmail.
5. Dropbox calls the registered callback with the code. I use the code to retrieve bearer token.
6. Problem:  now i try to register another user and require a different code from Dropbox. The problem occurs in step 3. After
   user    clicks on step 3, Dropbox does not show the sign-in with
   google or    email page, instead, calls back application with the
   same code as for    user 1.

I'm using the same machine for testing this scenario  and two different gmail addresses. My server runs on localhost. It was working before but stopped working without any intentional changes from me. I have tried debugging but I am not sure why this is happening, trying restarting client, server, even restarted my computer. But it doesn't show me the sign-in with google or email page.

My question is how does Dropbox know that it should show the sign-in page when the redirect link is clicked. I generated the redirect link using core API functions.

Maybe there is an error in my workflow, I am new to web development and have tried everything I know, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser?  User 1 use Edge, User 2 uses Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try that. I am using chrome for both users, in fact, i am using brackets and brackets is using chrome.

Comment: could it be that i made 100 calls to dropbox authorization (for testing) and i reached my limit for today?

Comment: This behavior is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633222/dropbox-oauth-token-flow-redirect-without-needing-to-click-allow/35634963#35634963

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I tried the force-reapprove flag. It showed the allow screen but then went on to callback with the previous user's code.This is log from redriect, not sure if it is relevant:
  Redirect {
    request: [Circular],
    followRedirect: true,
    followRedirects: true,
    followAllRedirects: false,
    followOriginalHttpMethod: false,
    allowRedirect: [Function],
    maxRedirects: 10,
    redirects: [],
    redirectsFollowed: 0,
    removeRefererHeader: false },

Comment: Update: I tried opening the link in FireFox instead of Chrome which is used by Brackets and it seems to work fine. In FireFox it shows the first user's email as default and i changed it. It showed this even though I am signed out of both gmail addresses. I guess switching multiple times between gmail address makes Chrome behave in a weird manner, or maybe 'Google' does not allow this 'foolish' behavior and keeps using the first email since they are monitoring everything :D